# creating files with Tauri & Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tauri

Hello can someone tell me how I can store and create files in **users/appdata/my-app-name** with Tauri & Reactjs

I tried searching on google, youtube but I couldn't find anything

also, I tried this module but I don't know how to use them

```
import { BaseDirectory, createDir } from "@tauri-apps/api/fs";
```

Answer (score 1):

Before even working with the tauri fs you need to make sure in the „tauri.conf.json“ file the fs is enabled in the allow list:

```
    {
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "fs": {
        "all": true, // enable all FS APIs
        "readFile": true,
        "writeFile": true,
        "readDir": true,
        "copyFile": true,
        "createDir": true,
        "removeDir": true,
        "removeFile": true,
        "renameFile": true,
        "exists": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I saw in your question you want to store something in appdata folder:

```
const appDataDir = BaseDirectory.AppData;
```

Now let's assume you want to make a json file in this folder:

```
await writeTextFile("example.json", "example textcontent in json", {dir: appDataDir, });
```

As you see you need to make sure it's **async**! This is just ex. for textfile, it's the same for a regular file. You could also pass for the „dir“ the „Basedirectory.AppData“ directly instead of the const „appDataDir“ we've made earlier.

Now let's assume you want to make your own folder (as it seems like the most suitable case) for the app in the AppData folder:

```
async function makeDir() {
try {
  if (!(await exists("OwnAppName", { dir: appDataDir }))) {
    await createDir("OwnAppName", { dir: appDataDir });
  }
} catch (err: any) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

}

This function creates a folder where you want it to be if it doesn't exist already (I've written it, it's not from the tauri docs)

And now finally let's assume you want to put the json we made earlier in this folder:

```
const filePath = "./OwnAppName/example.json";
```

The path to the file if you try to access it from AppData folder!

Then:

```
await writeTextFile(filePath, "example textcontent in json", {dir: appDataDir, });
```

This would place it inside the „OwnAppName“ we created earlier.

For more documentation look here:
https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/fs#writetextfile

If you need further help don't hesitate to ask more in the comments! Hope it helps!